# OS process management from Erlang

Tags: process, erlang, operating-system

What's the best way to do OS process management from Erlang? I need to be able to spawn child OS processes, write to the child's stdin, read from both stdout and stderr, send kill signals, and get notified of exit codes. I don't see that this is possible with what's in erts.

I know about [erlexec](http://code.google.com/p/erlexec/), but I don't know if it's stable or if anyone is actually using it in anger.  Are there any other options, or is that the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Port](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html) programs are the best way to do this. Port programs are safe and won't harm the Erlang VM, and if they crash or mis-behave can be killed and restarted like any other Erlang process.

Port *Drivers* are different and if they mis-behave can bring down the entire Erlang VM.

Comment: Ok. erlexec is a port program designed for running arbitrary child processes, so it looks at least like the right approach. It's a little weird that nobody else seems to have used it, though - is it really that uncommon a requirement?

Comment: Writing Port wrapper programs in just about any reasonable language is very simple, C and Python both have libraries for converting terms to binaries and back again to language native structures. `erlexec` is a general purpose wrapper program for any arbitrary executable. If you want specific behavior, and most people do, they write their own Port wrapper program. I usually use Python since they are small proxy programs with little logic and performance of the serialization and deserialization isn't usually and issue.

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang standard way to manage OS processes is [ports](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html).

Exit status of spawned OS process will be sent as a message if option `exit_status` added to [open_port](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2):

```
1> P = open_port({spawn, "/bin/ls unknown_file_name"}, [exit_status]).
#Port<0.486>
/bin/ls: cannot access unknown_file_name: No such file or directory
2> flush().
Shell got {#Port<0.486>,{exit_status,2}}
ok
```

Data can be written to stdin of spawned OS process by sending a message to port or by [port_command](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_command-2) function and stdout content will be sent as a message. (Note also `{line, L}` and `{packet, N}` options of `open_port`):

```
1> P = open_port({spawn, "/bin/cat"}, [stream, binary]).
#Port<0.486>
2> true = port_command(P, <<"data">>).
true
3> flush().
Shell got {#Port<0.486>,{data,<<"data">>}}
ok
4> true = port_close(P).
true
```

Stderr also can be redirected to stdout:

```
1> P = open_port({spawn, "/bin/ls unknown_file_name"}, [stderr_to_stdout, binary]).
#Port<0.486>
2> flush().
Shell got {#Port<0.486>,
    {data,<<"/bin/ls: cannot access unknown_file_name: No such file or directory\n">>}}
ok
```

However you can't send kill signals with ports but if you close port by sending a message to port or by calling [port_close](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_close-1) external process can exit by [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE) signal.